If ethereum is completely p2p then how do we efficiently discover network-scoped (gloal) info like no of peers in the network?
In order to query an info like the no of peers in the network it would take an order of magnitude of O(n2) where n is the no of peers in the network since each peer would sent the req of no of peers to their peers and so on.
Are there master nodes that keep track of this information?
I ask this because algorithms like RANDAO require such global or holistic info to operate so I figured there must be a provision for this.
